# Attach responsive image to the bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to make my design responsive. So, I stucked with a problem. I have a section. And in this section I have a pic. I need this pic to be on the bottom of this section. Always. Even if my screen will be super wide.

FULL HTML ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Postanite finančni svetovalec</title>
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/device-mockups/device-mockups.min.css">
</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Postanite finančni svetovalec</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Poklic</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#features">Prednosti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Priložnost</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <div class="header-content-inner">
                            <h1>Izberite poklic s perspektivo in postanite finančni svetovalec</h1>
                            <a href="#download" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl page-scroll">Začnite danes!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                   <div class="device-container">

                    <!--<div style="height: auto; width: auto;">-->
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="businessman">
                    <img src="img/businessman.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              <div class="button">
           </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="download" class="download bg-primary text-center">
    <div class="blockToCenter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Zakaj postati finančni svetovalec?</h2>
                    <p>Finančni svetovalci imajo veliko več zaposlitvenih priložnosti, kot ostali poklici. Pridobite praktično in uporabno znanje in se jim pridružite!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="generate.js"></script>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="Prednosti" class="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>Prednosti poklica</h2>
                        <p class="text-muted">Koristi, ki jih boste imeli kot finančni svetovalec so:</p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="device-container">

                        <img src="img/benef.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-screen-smartphone text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Nadpovprečen zaslužek</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Uspešni finančni svetovalci uživajo nadpovprečen zaslužek</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <h3>Sodobno okolje</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Delo poteka v sodobnih pisarniških prostorih z odličnimi pogoji za delo</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <h3>Ugled</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Imejte ugled v lokalnem okolju in širše</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <h3>Vrhunski partnerji</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Delo z najuglednejšimi poslovnimi partnerji v Evropi in svetu.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Pridružite se timu uspešnih finančnih svetovalcev!</h2>

        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="features" class="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>Postanite sam svoj šef</h2>
                        <p class="text-muted">Prav vi ste primerni za finančnega svetovalca, saj:</p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="device-container">

                        <img src="img/benef.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <h3>Prevzemate odgovornost</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Prevzeli ste odgovornost za svojo prihodnost in za prihodnost vaše družine</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <h3>Razvijate svoj potencial</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Imate potencial in vam je mar za vaš osebni in strokovni razvoj</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-present text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Želite postati uspešni</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Želite si uspeha, svobode in uresničitve življenjskih ciljev</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-lock-open text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Ste drzni</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Drznete si spoznati nove svetove in področja</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cta">
        <div class="cta-content">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Ne oklevajte.<br>Udeležite se usposabljanja!</h2>
                <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl page-scroll">Ugotovite kaj obsega program!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="Specializacija" class="contact bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img/first.png">
        <p class="review">Very good company. I am just trying to leave there some kind words.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img/second.png">
        <p class="review">We are looking forward to cooperate with you again.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img/third.png">
        <p class="review">Cooperation with you was really nice! Can't wait to work with you again.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!--
            <h2>Specializacija</h2>
            <p>Na finančnem parketu se lahko osredotočate v eno ali več specialnih področjih in se izmojstrite v naložbenega, borznega, zavarovalniškega eksperta ali pa na primer postanete
najboljši poznavalec trga plemenitih kovin.</p>
            <p>Samo od vas je odvisno, v kateri smeri boste poglabljali svoje znanje. Vam v prid govori dejstvo, da število investitorjev, ki iščejo nasvet strokovnjaka tudi v Sloveniji neprestano in
skokovito narašča.</p>
        </div>-->
    </section>
<section id="Priložnost" class="features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <h2>Izkoristite odlično priložnost</h2>
                        <p class="text-muted">Ravno zdaj je pravi čas za finančno svetovanje, ker je:</p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="device-container">

                        <img src="img/benef.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">

                       <!-- <div class="device-mockup iphone6_plus portrait white">
                            <div class="device">
                                <div class="screen">

                                    <img src="img/demo-screen-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
                                <div class="button">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-screen-smartphone text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Perspektiven poklic</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Finančni svetovalec poklic z največjo perspektivo</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-camera text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Malo konkurence</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Osebnih svetovalcev v Sloveniji premalo in konkurence praktično ni,</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-present text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Hitra rast</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">finančna industrija ena najhitreje rastočih panog v svetu sploh</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="feature-item">
                                    <!--<i class="icon-lock-open text-primary"></i>-->
                                    <h3>Velike potrebe</h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Večina prebivalstva finančno nepismena in potrebuje pomoč strokovnjaka</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p>&copy; 2016 Start Bootstrap. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Privacy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Terms</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/new-age.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

FULL CSS ->

```
.heading-font {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.body-font {
  font-family: 'Muli', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}
.alt-font {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Muli', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}
a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  color: #fdcc52;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #fcbd20;
}
hr {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1);
}
hr.light {
  border-color: white;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fdcc52;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fcbd20;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #222222;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
  color: #fdcc52;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fdcc52 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #222222;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #fdcc52;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #222222;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: #fdcc52;
  }
}


header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), #7b4397;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  color: white;
}
header .header-content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 150px auto;

}
header .header-content .header-content-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
header .header-content .header-content-inner .list-badges {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
header .header-content .header-content-inner .list-badges img {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header .device-container {

}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    margin-top: 60%;
  }

  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 360px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    margin-top: 40%;

  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    margin-top: 40%;

  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  header .header-content {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }

  header .device-container {
    max-width: none;
    max-height: calc(0vh);
    margin-top: 30%;

  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
section h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
section.download {
  padding: 150px 0;
  position: relative;
}
section.download h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}
section.download .badges .badge-link {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
section.download .badges .badge-link:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.download .badges .badge-link img {
  height: 60px;
}

section.download .forma {
  margin-top:6%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.download .badges .badge-link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.download h2 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
section.features .section-heading {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
section.features .section-heading h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
section.features .section-heading p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.features .device-container,
section.features .feature-item {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section.features .feature-item i {
  font-size: 80px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  header .device-container img {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  section.features .device-container,
  section.features .feature-item {
    max-width: none;
  }
}
section.cta {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('../img/bg-cta.jpg');
  padding: 250px 0;
}
section.cta .cta-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
section.cta .cta-content h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 450px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.cta .cta-content h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

section.cta .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
section.contact {
  text-align: center;
}
section.contact h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
section.contact h2 i {
  color: #dd4b39;
}
section.contact ul.list-social {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li a {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-twitter a {
  background-color: #1da1f2;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li.social-twitter a:hover {
  background-color: #0d95e8;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li.social-facebook a {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li.social-facebook a:hover {
  background-color: #344e86;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li.social-google-plus a {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}
section.contact ul.list-social li.social-google-plus a:hover {
  background-color: #d73925;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 25px 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}
footer p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
footer ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
footer ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
footer ul li a:hover,
footer ul li a:focus,
footer ul li a:active,
footer ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.bg-primary {
  background: #fdcc52;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF936F, #FFA07D);
  background: linear-gradient(#FF936F, #FFA07D);
}
.text-primary {
  color: #fdcc52;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.btn-outline {
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline:active,
.btn-outline.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #fdcc52;
  border-color: #fdcc52;
}
.btn {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 300px;
}
.btn-xl {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}
::selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}
img::selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
img::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222222;
}
```

[image: I need this guy to be on the bottom!!!]

Comment: You'll need to provide more code. Enough for us to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add the following CSS to your existing CSS.

Check demo at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/VKvdqv?editors=1100)**

I hope it work

CSS:

```
.device-container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height:100%;
}
.businessman img {
  max-width: 200px; 

}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Modified CSS**

demo at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/qabkkQ?editors=1100)**

CSS:

```
.heading-font {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.body-font {
  font-family: 'Muli', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

.alt-font {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Muli', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  color: #fdcc52;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #fcbd20;
}

hr {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1);
}

hr.light {
  border-color: white;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fdcc52;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fcbd20;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li > a {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #222222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
  color: #fdcc52;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fdcc52 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #222222;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #fdcc52;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #222222;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: #fdcc52;
  }
}

header {
  /* height: 100%; */
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), #7b4397;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png"), linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  color: white;
}

header .header-content {
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 150px auto; */
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner .list-badges {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner .list-badges img {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

header .device-container {}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    /*margin-top: 60%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;*/
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 360px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    /* margin-top: 40%; */
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    /* margin-top: 40%; */
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    /*min-height: 100%;*/
  }
  header .header-content {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    /*  max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); */
  }
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  header .device-container {
    /* max-width: none;
    max-height: calc(0vh);
    margin-top: 30%; */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

section h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

section.download {
  padding: 150px 0;
  position: relative;
}

section.download h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}

section.download .badges .badge-link {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

section.download .badges .badge-link:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.download .badges .badge-link img {
  height: 60px;
}

section.download .forma {
  margin-top: 6%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.download .badges .badge-link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.download h2 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}

section.features .section-heading {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

section.features .section-heading h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

section.features .section-heading p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.features .device-container,
section.features .feature-item {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section.features .feature-item i {
  font-size: 80px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #7b4397, #dc2430);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  /*header .device-container img {
    display: none;
  }*/
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  section.features .device-container,
  section.features .feature-item {
    max-width: none;
  }
}

section.cta {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('../img/bg-cta.jpg');
  padding: 250px 0;
}

section.cta .cta-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

section.cta .cta-content h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 450px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section.cta .cta-content h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

section.cta .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section.contact {
  text-align: center;
}

section.contact h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

section.contact h2 i {
  color: #dd4b39;
}

section.contact ul.list-social {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li a {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-twitter a {
  background-color: #1da1f2;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-twitter a:hover {
  background-color: #0d95e8;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-facebook a {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-facebook a:hover {
  background-color: #344e86;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-google-plus a {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

section.contact ul.list-social li.social-google-plus a:hover {
  background-color: #d73925;
}

footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 25px 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}

footer ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

footer ul li a:hover,
footer ul li a:focus,
footer ul li a:active,
footer ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bg-primary {
  background: #fdcc52;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF936F, #FFA07D);
  background: linear-gradient(#FF936F, #FFA07D);
}

.text-primary {
  color: #fdcc52;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-outline {
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline:active,
.btn-outline.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #fdcc52;
  border-color: #fdcc52;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 300px;
}

.btn-xl {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #222222;
}

img::selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

img::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222222;
}

header {
  background: wheat;
}

.device-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

.businessman img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I added this code and "guy in the header" decided to go to the top of the screen...

Comment: you can check it by yourself (https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmn16tpoy8torcz/design%202.zip?dl=0) (this version without your code)

Comment: Please check the modified CSS with demo I have **updated my answer**. Earlier mine CSS overridden by your CSS. I hope you are smart enough to get the idea from the example and implement it in your code.  Enjoy :)